# How to append XML root element to an existing xml string

Tags: apex, apexrest

I have XML string like below in that I have to add root element and some attribute using apex. I was searching this for whole day but I din't get any key point. I saw there is some support for DOM and XML stream reader/writer but I am not sure how to achieve this.

**My XML String**

```
<Request>
  <AuthenticationDetail>
    <UserCredential>
      <Key>*******</Key>
      <Password>********</Password>
    </UserCredential>
  </AuthenticationDetail>
</Request>
```

**Expected XML String**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:m0="http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<Request xmlns="http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21">
      <AuthenticationDetail>
        <UserCredential>
          <Key>*******</Key>
          <Password>********</Password>
        </UserCredential>
      </AuthenticationDetail>
    </Request>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If any one achieved this in Apex can you please share the code or any pointer/information is highly appreciated. I am struggling in this for past 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      string  XMLString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Request><AuthenticationDetail><UserCredential><Key>*******</Key><Password>********</Password></UserCredential></AuthenticationDetail></Request>';
      DOM.Document doc=new DOM.Document();
      String soapenv = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
      String soapenc = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding';
      String xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
      String xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'; 
      String m0='http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21';
      doc.load(XMLString);
     DOM.Document docNew = new DOM.Document();
    dom.XmlNode envelope= docNew.createRootElement('Envelope',SOAPENV,'SOAP-ENV');
    envelope.setNamespace('SOAP-ENV',SOAPENV);
    envelope.setNamespace('xmlns',m0);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('SOAP-ENV',soapenv,m0,null);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('SOAP-ENC',soapenc,m0,null);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('xsi',xsi,m0,null);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('xsd',xsd,m0,null);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('m0',m0,m0,null);
    envelope.removeAttribute('SOAP-ENV',m0);
    envelope.removeAttribute('xmlns',m0);
    dom.XmlNode body = envelope.addChildElement('SOAP-ENV:Body',null,null);
    //adding the root Element into the new document
    dom.XmlNode rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
      string rootElementName=rootNode.getName();
      string rootElementText=rootNode.getText();
      string rootElementNamespace=rootNode.getNamespace();
      string rootElementprefix=null;
      if(rootElementNamespace!=null)
      {
        rootElementprefix= rootNode.getPrefixFor(rootElementNamespace);
      }
    dom.XmlNode domroot = body.addChildElement(rootElementName,rootElementNamespace,rootElementprefix);
    if(rootNode.getAttributeCount()>0){
        for(integer i=0;i<rootNode.getAttributeCount();i++){
           domroot.setAttribute(rootNode.getAttributeKeyAt(i),rootNode.getAttributeValue(rootNode.getAttributeKeyAt(i),rootNode.getNamespace()));
           }
    }
    if(rootNode.getText()!=null){
             domroot.addTextNode(rootNode.getText());
        }

   process(doc.getRootElement().getChildElements(),domroot);

   //Iterating every child element of the doc and adding it in doc new
   Public void process(Dom.XmlNode[] domlist,dom.XmlNode domroot){
    for (Dom.XmlNode child : domlist) {
        Dom.XmlNode addition = domroot.addChildElement(child.getName(),child.getNamespace(),child.getNamespace()!=null ? child.getPrefixFor(child.getNamespace()) :null);
        if(child.getAttributeCount()>0){
        for(integer i=0;i<child.getAttributeCount();i++){
           addition.setAttribute(child.getAttributeKeyAt(i),child.getAttributeValue(child.getAttributeKeyAt(i),child.getNamespace()));
           }
        }
        if(child.getText()!=null){
             addition.addTextNode(child.getText());
        }
        System.debug(child.getChildElements());
        process(child.getChildElements(),addition);
      }
     }
    System.debug(docNew.toXmlString());
```

I have updated the code.Now You can add envelope and body can be added with the response.

Comment: @vidyasagaran. Thank you so much for your code but my scenario is I am getting the XML string mentioned above as response from third party . In that XML string I need to append the `envelope` and `body` tag. I can't create the whole XML again.

Comment: Now I have modified the code as per your comment

Comment: Thank you so much. This code really helps me out to learn a lot about XML serialization. I have some clarification. If i don't want to have the below attribute in the envelope tag `xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xmlns ="http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21"` and I also don't want to create the root tag `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` How I can achieve this.

Comment: Its not added the attribute also in the <request> tag `<Request xmlns="http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21">`. I got stuck in the above two points. one is removing the XML Declaration and `xmlns:xmlns` attribute and second one is adding the namespace in the `<request>` tag.

Comment: updated all the changes in this post:https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/259979/how-to-omit-remove-xml-declaration-using-dom/260004#260004

Comment: Is it possible to view the complete xmlstring in system.debug(). It's getting truncated in debug logs. Any suggestions from your end

Comment: execute it in workbench you can see the full xmlstring