# How to omit/remove xml declaration using DOM

Tags: apex, java

I have code which appends XML header to the existing xmlstring. In that I am getting response with XML declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and I have add the attribute in my  Tag like `<Request xmlns="http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21">`

**Code**

```
string  XMLString = '<Request><AuthenticationDetail><UserCredential><Key>*******</Key><Password>********</Password></UserCredential></AuthenticationDetail></Request>';
      DOM.Document doc=new DOM.Document();
      String soapenv = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
      String soapenc = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding';
      String xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
      String xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'; 
      String m0='http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21';
      doc.load(XMLString);
     DOM.Document docNew = new DOM.Document();
    dom.XmlNode envelope= docNew.createRootElement('Envelope',SOAPENV,'SOAP-ENV');
    envelope.setNamespace('SOAP-ENV',SOAPENV);
    envelope.setNamespace('xmlns',m0);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('SOAP-ENV',soapenv,m0,null);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('SOAP-ENC',soapenc,m0,null);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('xsi',xsi,m0,null);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('xsd',xsd,m0,null);
    envelope.setAttributeNS('m0',m0,m0,null);
    envelope.removeAttribute('SOAP-ENV',m0);
    envelope.removeAttribute('xmlns',m0);
    dom.XmlNode body = envelope.addChildElement('SOAP-ENV:Body',null,null);
    //adding the root Element into the new document
    dom.XmlNode rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
      string rootElementName=rootNode.getName();
      string rootElementText=rootNode.getText();
      string rootElementNamespace=rootNode.getNamespace();
      string rootElementprefix=null;
      if(rootElementNamespace!=null)
      {
        rootElementprefix= rootNode.getPrefixFor(rootElementNamespace);
      }
    dom.XmlNode domroot = body.addChildElement(rootElementName,rootElementNamespace,rootElementprefix);
    if(rootNode.getAttributeCount()>0){
        for(integer i=0;i<rootNode.getAttributeCount();i++){
           domroot.setAttribute(rootNode.getAttributeKeyAt(i),rootNode.getAttributeValue(rootNode.getAttributeKeyAt(i),rootNode.getNamespace()));
           }
    }
    if(rootNode.getText()!=null){
             domroot.addTextNode(rootNode.getText());
        }

   process(doc.getRootElement().getChildElements(),domroot);

   //Iterating every child element of the doc and adding it in doc new
   Public void process(Dom.XmlNode[] domlist,dom.XmlNode domroot){
    for (Dom.XmlNode child : domlist) {
        Dom.XmlNode addition = domroot.addChildElement(child.getName(),child.getNamespace(),child.getNamespace()!=null ? child.getPrefixFor(child.getNamespace()) :null);
        if(child.getAttributeCount()>0){
        for(integer i=0;i<child.getAttributeCount();i++){
           addition.setAttribute(child.getAttributeKeyAt(i),child.getAttributeValue(child.getAttributeKeyAt(i),child.getNamespace()));
           }
        }
        if(child.getText()!=null){
             addition.addTextNode(child.getText());
        }
        System.debug(child.getChildElements());
        process(child.getChildElements(),addition);
      }
     }
    System.debug(docNew.toXmlString());
```

**Output**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:m0="http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xmlns="http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<Request>
<AuthenticationDetail>
            <UserCredential>
              <Key>*******</Key>
              <Password>********</Password>
            </UserCredential>
          </AuthenticationDetail>
        </Request>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
        </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:m0="http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<Request xmlns="http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21"><AuthenticationDetail>
        <UserCredential>
          <Key>*******</Key>
          <Password>********</Password>
        </UserCredential>
      </AuthenticationDetail>
    </Request>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)**I am getting response with XML declaration** 
 Why you want to remove the declaration XML Parser will parse it properly.
2) I have updated the code change that you are asking for below

```
string  XMLString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Request><AuthenticationDetail><UserCredential><Key>*******</Key><Password>********</Password></UserCredential></AuthenticationDetail></Request>';
DOM.Document doc=new DOM.Document();
doc.load(XMLString);
DOM.Document docNew = new DOM.Document();
dom.XmlNode envelope= docNew.createRootElement('SOAP-ENV:Envelope',null,null);
envelope.setAttribute('xmlns:SOAP-ENV','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
envelope.setAttribute('xmlns:SOAP-ENC','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding');
envelope.setAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
envelope.setAttribute('xmlns:xsd','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema');
envelope.setAttribute('xmlns:m0','http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21');
System.debug(envelope.getAttributeCount());
dom.XmlNode body = envelope.addChildElement('SOAP-ENV:Body',null,null);
//adding the root Element into the new document
dom.XmlNode rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
  string rootElementName=rootNode.getName();
  string rootElementText=rootNode.getText();
  string rootElementNamespace=rootNode.getNamespace();
  string rootElementprefix=null;
  if(rootElementNamespace!=null)
  {
    rootElementprefix= rootNode.getPrefixFor(rootElementNamespace);
  }
  dom.XmlNode domroot = body.addChildElement(rootElementName,rootElementNamespace,rootElementprefix);
  if(rootNode.getAttributeCount()>0){
    for(integer i=0;i<rootNode.getAttributeCount();i++){
       domroot.setAttribute(rootNode.getAttributeKeyAt(i),rootNode.getAttributeValue(rootNode.getAttributeKeyAt(i),rootNode.getNamespace()));
       }
   }else if (rootElementName=='Request'){
    domroot.setAttribute('xmlns','http://abc.com/ws/motor/v21');
   }
   if(rootNode.getText()!=null){
         domroot.addTextNode(rootNode.getText());
    }

    process(doc.getRootElement().getChildElements(),domroot);

    //Iterating every child element of the doc and adding it in doc new
    Public void process(Dom.XmlNode[] domlist,dom.XmlNode domroot){
     for (Dom.XmlNode child : domlist) {
     Dom.XmlNode addition = domroot.addChildElement(child.getName(),child.getNamespace(),child.getNamespace()!=null ? child.getPrefixFor(child.getNamespace()) :null);
     if(child.getAttributeCount()>0){
     for(integer i=0;i<child.getAttributeCount();i++){

      addition.setAttribute(child.getAttributeKeyAt(i),child.getAttributeValue(child.getAttributeKeyAt(i),child.getNamespace()));
       }
    }

     if(child.getText()!=null){
         addition.addTextNode(child.getText());
     }
    System.debug(child.getChildElements());
    process(child.getChildElements(),addition);
  }
 }
 string xmlValue=docNew.toXmlString().remove('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
  System.debug(xmlValue);
```

Comment: Thank you Vidhyasagaran . I want to remove XML declaration because I want to send this response to third party as http request. They not accepting  the XML declaration. It's giving 400 bad request error

Comment: You are giving them string as request?

Comment: Yes I am passing the xml string as soap http request. Do you have any other suggestion to do it in a better way?

Comment: Now check I have removed XML declaration